# How do I safely display emails in a browser, ie. only allow HTML, no javascript or outside sources?

Tags: php, email, xss, html-email

I've searched a lot but couldn't find the appropriate solutions to allow all html except for javascript, outside sources, or any other XSS attacks. I want to be able to display user-created emails in the browser, which inherently should allow html, head, body, style, and other tags. Most topics related to XSS filtering rely on HTMLPurifier or other solutions which aren't designed for full html output.

My best solution I found thus far is to use the [XSS filter in codeigniter](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php) and tweak it a bit to allow more html (like body tags). However, I'm afraid I'll accidentally allow something dangerous.

Are there any open-source solutions for what I'm trying to do? Surely it's been done before?

Comment: do you want to disable javascript in your browser? Then check this -> http://www.cert.org/tech_tips/securing_browser/

Comment: Definitely don't want to disable javascript in my browser. This is for a website, I can't have all users turn off javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function [strip_tags([allowed tags])](http://php.net/strip_tags) Include all the tags you want to allow and leave out `<script>`.

Comment: strip_tags is not safe against XSS. There's a ton that can get past it.

Comment: This thread might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605629/php-prevent-xss-with-strip-tags