# twig striptags and html special chars

Tags: html, symfony, twig, special-characters, strip

I am using twig to render a view and I am using the striptags filter to remove html tags.
However, html special chars are now rendered as text as the whole element is surrounded by "".
How can I either strip special chars or render them, while still using the striptags function ?

Example :

```
{{ organization.content|striptags("&nbsp;&gt;")|truncate(200, '...') }}
```

or

```
{{ organization.content|striptags|truncate(200, '...') }}
```

Output:

```
"QUI SOMMES NOUS ?&nbsp;&gt; NOS LOCAUXNOS LOCAUXDepuis 1995,  Ce lieu chargé d’histoire et de tradition s’inscrit dans les valeurs"
```

Comment: not working but I finally solved it. thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If it could help someone else, here is my solution

```
{{ organization.content|striptags|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') }}
```

You can also add a trim filter to remove spaces before and after.
And then, you truncate or slice your organization.content

**EDIT November 2017**

If you want to keep the "\n" break lines combined with a truncate, you can do

`{{ organization.content|striptags|truncate(140, true, '...')|raw|nl2br }}`

Comment: Huge thanks for that answer: short, concise and exactly what I searched.

Comment: I was still getting some strange special characters so I tried a few other things. This is what worked for me: 
`{{ organization.content|striptags|raw }}`

Comment: Be careful with raw, as it may have XSS issues. See also https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2215#issuecomment-258088927

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, this worked for me:

```
{{ variable |convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') | raw }}
```

Answer (score 7):

I was trying some of, among others, these answers:

```
{{ organization.content|striptags|truncate(200, true) }}
{{ organization.content|raw|striptags|truncate(200, true) }}
{{ organization.content|striptags|raw|truncate(200, true) }}
etc.
```

And still got strange characters in the final form. What helped me, is putting the `raw` filter on the end of all operations, i.e:

```
{{ organization.content|striptags|truncate(200, '...')|raw }}
```

Comment: Be careful with raw, as it may have XSS issues. See also https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2215#issuecomment-258088927

Comment: Yeah, but I'm using `striptags` first. Doesn't it ensure that it will be secure?

Comment: I added the warning for the case where some tags may still be allowed. `striptags` with no allowed tags would be save save but with allowed tags `striptags('<allowed tags>')` not. Internally it uses php function strip_tags, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3605629/880188.

Answer (score 7):

### 2022 update | tested with Drupal 8.6.16

I tried the top voted recommendation. It worked ok with some symbols but not with others.

`raw`  filter seems to be working ok with all special characters.

like so

`{{ organization.content|striptags|raw }}`

Answer (score 5):

Arf, I finally found it :

I am using a custom twig filter that just applies a php function:

```
<span>{{ organization.shortDescription ?: php('html_entity_decode',organization.content|striptags|truncate(200, '...')) }}</span>
```

Now it renders correctly

My php extension:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Extension;

class phpExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('php', array($this, 'getPhp')),
        );
    }

    public function getPhp($function, $variable)
    {
        return $function($variable);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'php_extension';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is :

```
{{ organization.content|striptags|truncate(200, '...')|raw }}
```

With `|raw` always at the end.

Don't use `convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')`, you will encounter iconv issues.

Answer (score 1):

When I thought none of the above answers were working for me (`convert_encoding` running into `iconv()` issues in Drupal 9, and I thought `raw`, but because applying it on the argument side of an `{% embed %}` — as opposed to in the embedded template itself — didn't seem to help), another approach that seemed to work for me was:

```
{% autoescape false %}
  {{ organization.content|striptags|truncate(200, '...') }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

with that `false` part being key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved it byt this function below, using strip_tags.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Extension;

class filterHtmlExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('stripHtmlTags', array($this, 'stripHtmlTags')),
        );
    }


    public function stripHtmlTags($value)
    {

        $value_displayed = strip_tags($value);


        return $value_displayed ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
       return 'filter_html_extension';
    }
}
```