# How to truncate text and use the raw filter in Twig

Tags: twig, twig-extension, twig-filter

The issue is that the [raw Twig filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) must go at the end of the chain for it to work correctly and replace the HTML entities with their corresponding characters. This causes a problem as I need to also use the truncate function. The truncation is happening correctly but in the instances where the truncation happens in the middle of one of the HTML entity strings the raw function then fails to remove this entity.

Current solution:

```
{{ BlogPost.description|striptags|truncate(80)|raw }}
```

Input string:

```
<p>It supports your pupils to think like scientists &ndash;&nbsp;but that doesn&rsquo;t&nbsp;mean it&#39;s only for science!</p>"
```

What the current solution achieves:

```
It supports your pupils to think like scientists – but that doesn&rsq...
```

What I want to achieve:

```
It supports your pupils to think like scientists – but that doesn't m...
```

Comment: `&nbsp;` is not affected by `striptags`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [twig striptags and html special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670146/twig-striptags-and-html-special-chars)

Comment: Yes you are correct `&nbsp;` is not effected by `striptags`. That is there to strip the html tags and is working fine. The `raw` filter is the part which removes the HTML entities, this is also working fine except where the truncation breaks the HTML entity in half before it gets to the `raw` filter. When this happens the `raw` filter fails to remove the HTML entities. This is the specific problem which is why I also don't think it is a duplicate question.

Comment: Adding `convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')` before the truncate does solve the issue though. Would post a twigfiddle but the truncate filter is unknown there :)