# The secure way to use GET parameter in the DOM?

Tags: php, html, security, xss

Here is a simplified of my code:

```
$html = "<a class='myclass' href='/path?arg='" . $_GET['param']. "'>mylink</a>";
```

Today I was reading about XSS attack and I think my code is under XSS attack. Howver I'm not sure, but it smells that.

Anyway, if my thought is right, how can I avoid that? Based on some researches, one way is using `strip_tags()`. Now I want to know, can I rely on it? And is that fine enough?

Comment: Hey, yes you can try it out for yourself. Just pass <script>alert("Hello world");</script> in favour of your ?param= value. As this answer states: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605629/prevent-xss-with-strip-tags you have 2 options. Either strip_tags or encode the HTML. Either way will prevent XSS.

Comment: strip_tags() is not enough in your case, imagine what your output becomes when you call `index.php?param=' onclick='alert(1)` so what you need is htmlspecialchars()

Comment: @WillParky93 read the task and answer you linked carefully, it clearly states, that strip_tags() is not enough to prevent XSS

Comment: For me, Whenever building the HTML in my PHP code I use `htmlspecialchars()`. also you may need to consider using HTML templates or some sort of templates engine as it sanitize the HTML variables automatically for you to save you from forgetting something.

Answer (score 1):

This is about encode something with the correct function.
Always look what you want to product, then choose the encoder!

**Samples:**

When you are building HTML its good to use htmlspecialchars and/or htmlentities.

When you are build SQL its good to use for mysql PDO::quote or mysqli_real_escape_string.

**Answer:**

In your case, you are building an URL. For this you need to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

In addition you also need to escape it to correct HTML with [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), because you are building HTML in the next step.
See the sample in PHP manual -> urlencode link (Example #2).

Answer (score -1):

You should use **[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)** whenever you want to output a parameter that came from user.

`$variable = htmlspecialchars($_GET['param'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: This function is to get a correct HTML encoding. He is building a URL. In fact, spaces, question marks and some others are not escaped. his url will incorrect if he uses htmlspecialchars.